# Event Asp Mvc Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am beginner in asp.net mvc. I have in the view `Home.cshtml`

```
<button name ="del"  style="width:150px; height:30px;text-decoration:none;color:white;text-align:center;background-color:darkcyan;padding:5px;border-style:outset;border-width:2px;border-color:darkcyan"  onclick="@Url.Action("Delete", "Super",1)">Supprimer</button>
<button name ="edit"style="width:150px; height:30px;text-decoration:none;color:white;text-align:center;background-color:darkcyan;padding:5px;border-style:outset;border-width:2px;border-color:darkcyan" onclick="@Url.Action("Edit", "Super","val")">Editer</button>
```

When i click into the two buttons nothing is gone and the redirection didn't work.

1. why?
2. How can i change it to be correct?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste your code from global.asax

Comment: ` public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }`

Comment: What do you have in RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) ?

Comment: ` public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Ad_creation",
              url: "{controller}/{action}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Create" }
          );
        }`

Comment: Comment out route named "Ad_creation" and check DarrenDavis solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to be creating links like this in `MVC`.  Try using `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Edit", "Super");

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Super");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.108).aspx

For a button:

```
<input type="button" value="Supprimer" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Super")';" />
```

To specify parameters:

```
<input type="button" value="Supprimer" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Super", new { Id = 1 })';" />
```

Comment: i mean in click into button, i need the redirection

Comment: but if i need a parameter in the action it is not working for example `onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Super",1)';"` the url will be `Super/Delete` and an exception of missing args appears

Comment: @Lamloumi I think you read up on some basic MVC tutorials because this is the basis of the whole concept.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: I have found issues setting `.href`, thats why I set the `.location` directly. Not really cared enough to worry why it was happening to me at the time, perhaps your solution also works

Comment: @Rogier21 thanks for your advice :) , did you have a solution for this problem?

Comment: @Lamloumi yes, this answer is the best answer :) You are still abusing the framework by not using the proper methods `(@Html.ActionLink)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery in this case to improve the current quality of code as below

```
<input id="supprimer" type="button" value="Supprimer" />

$('#supprimer').click(function(){
   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Super")';
});
```

And in the best version, try to module that code with the [AMD pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)

Comment: My problem is in the action with arguments : in the cshtml i have `  <a type="button" style="width:150px; height:30px;text-decoration:none;color:white;text-align:center;background-color:darkcyan;padding:5px;border-style:outset;border-width:2px;border-color:darkcyan" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Super",new { Id = 1 })">Editer</a>` and in the controller i have `public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Admin",id);
        }`. i have as an url `Admin/Edit` without argument `id`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `onclick` is a javascript event, and thus requires javascript code. You are just setting it as a URL, which will do nothing.

One option (and I am not saying it is the best) would be to change it to:

```
onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Delete", "Super", new { id = 1 })';"
```

Comment: the url will be without 1 ie `Super/Delete` so an error of missing args appears

Comment: @Lamloumi: So change the URL bit, that wasn't really the question. By the way, it would be much better to use an `a` tag for links, and use `Html.ActionLink(...)`

Comment: the same error and the url is still the same even after your updating code

Comment: the error is that the url is without the argument `Super/delete` not `Super/delete/1`

Comment: i did `<a type="button" style="width:150px; height:30px;text-decoration:none;color:white;text-align:center;background-color:darkcyan;padding:5px;border-style:outset;border-width:2px;border-color:darkcyan" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Super",new { Id = 1 })">Editer</a>` and in the controller `public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Admin",id);
        }` . but the url is `Admin/Edit` not `Admin/Edit/1`

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution :

```
 <a type="button"   style="width:150px; height:30px;text-decoration:none;color:white;text-align:center;background-color:darkcyan;padding:5px;border-style:outset;border-width:2px;border-color:darkcyan;margin-left:25px"  href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Super",new { Id = 1 })">Supprimer</a>
    <a type="button" style="width:150px; height:30px;text-decoration:none;color:white;text-align:center;background-color:darkcyan;padding:5px;border-style:outset;border-width:2px;border-color:darkcyan" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Super",new { Id = 1 })">Editer</a>
```

In the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            int id2 = id;


           return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Admin", new {id = id2});
        }
```